# Calling unmanaged C DLL function from C# (with pointer to struct and pointer to bool array)

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I’ve just joined the site, and this is my first posting here.
I could really do with some help calling an unmanaged DLL function from my C# application. I've been searching around, and have found various similar questions, but nothing which quite fits what I need.

The function I need to call is:

```
int DevConfig(struct A *a, int b, unsigned int c, BOOL *d);
```

Where A is defined as:

```
struct A
{
    double f[4];    
    unsigned int df[4];
    unsigned int dfn[4];
    double *dc[4];
    float dg[4];
    float g;
    UCHAR gs;
};
```

I’m getting a bit stuck and confused as to how to handle this in the C#. I think I need to do something like this, but I know it’s not quite right:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct A
{
    public double[] f = new double[4];
    public uint[] df = new uint[4];
    public uint[] dfn = new uint[4];
    public double[,] dc = new uint[4,256];
    public float[] dg = new float[4];
    public float g;
    public byte gs;
}

[DllImport("DevControl.dll")]
static extern int DevConfig (ref A a, int b, uint c, bool[] d);
```

I think this is the correct approach, but I’m confused about the array of pointers to doubles (double *dc[4]), and also the pointer to an array of Boolean (BOOL *d).
Please could someone help me get this right?

**Edit with more info:**
In the case of this function, data flows from the C# to the DLL. That is, the C# allocates the memory.
I was thinking of specifing dc as follows, unless it's easier to do it another way:

```
double[,] dc = new double[4, 256];
```

The size of this array is always 4 x 256. Somehow I need to marshal this into the IntPtr[] field of the struct?

And for the bool array:

```
bool[] d = new bool[8];
```

The length of this array may vary, it is not necessarily always 8 (but the DLL knows how long it is via one of the other parameters passed in).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The struct needs to look like this:

```
public struct A
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=4)]
    public double[];
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=4)]
    public uint[] df;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=4)]
    public uint[] dfn;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=4)]
    public IntPtr[] dc;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=4)]
    public float[] dg;
    public float g;
    public byte gs;
}
```

The key point is that these arrays are stored inline in the struct and therefore must be marshalled using `UnmanagedType.ByValArray`.

The function declaration should be:

```
[DllImport("DevControl.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int DevConfig (ref A a, int b, uint c, bool[] d);
```

This does assume that the final parameter is an array rather than a pointer to a single boolean. Only you know that. Note also the calling convention. As written, your unmanaged function is `cdecl`. And you do need to specify that in the p/invoke.

---

Now, the problem that you will face is the 2D array in the struct, `dc`. The only way to handle that is to manually allocate and marshal unmanaged memory. You cannot use a `double[,]` because that simply does not map to `double*[]`. Hence you need `IntPtr[]` and then some use of the `Marshal` class to finish the job. Exactly how all that is to be done cannot be discerned from the question. It does not specify who allocates the memory.

---

You state in an update that you want to allocate the double arrays in the C# to pass to the unmanaged code. Some example code for that:

```
IntPtr[] CreateUnmanagedArrays(double[][] arr)
{
    IntPtr[] result = new IntPtr[arr.Length];
    for (int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(arr[i].Length*sizeof(double));
        Marshal.Copy(arr[i], 0, result[i], arr[i].Length);
    }
    return result;
}

void DestroyUnmanagedArrays(IntPtr[] arr)
{
    for (int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++)
    {
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(arr[i]);
        arr[i] = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you David, this is very helpful information. (I can't mark your answer as "useful" because I don't have any reputation yet).

Comment: No probs. I've given you as much rep as I'm allowed to!

Comment: Regarding the IntPtr[], I will be creating the data in the C# and therefore allocating the memory there. Are you able to point me at how I should be using Marshal to handle this? The bool is indeed an array, also allocated in the C# and passed by pointer into the DLL. Regarding CallingConvention, the source code for the DLL appears to use __declspec( dllexport ), without specifying a calling convention such as cdecl or stdcall. Does that mean cdecl is the correct convention for me to use? Many thanks again.

Comment: Unless it is specified explicitly, the C code will use `cdecl`. I'll add an update to the question regarding the double arrays. Let me be clear though, the data flows from C# down to C++? You only need it to go in that direction? And in what form are these double arrays held in your C# code? An update to the question would help me get this right for you.

Comment: David, I have added an edit to the bottom of my question, which I hope clarifies my intentions.

Comment: OK, getting there. Could you possibly supply the input as `double[][]`. That's much easier to use than `double[,]`.

Comment: Yes, double[][] would also be fine!

Comment: Superb, thank you so much! You could not have been more helpful. One last point of clarification if you wouldn't mind: do I need [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)], or is this not necessary?

Comment: That is the default for a `struct`. So it makes no difference whether you add it or not. It comes down to a choice on your part. Do you prefer to be explicit and not have to try to remember what the default is? Up to you.

Answer (score 2):

```
   [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct A
    {

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.R8)]
        public double[] f;

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uint[] df;

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uint[] dfn;

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.SysUInt)]
        public System.IntPtr[] dc;

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.R4)]
        public float[] dg;

        public float g;

        public byte gs;
    }


[DllImportAttribute("DevControl.dll", EntryPoint = "DevConfig")]
public static extern int DevConfig(ref A a, int b, uint c, ref int d);
```

Comment: Thank you Sameer, I hadn't considered IntPtr[].